Spring Boot Kafka Listener Concurrency less than number of partitions
How does the consumption of Kafka messages look like when having for instance

12 partitions per topic
2 microservices running
each microservice with a concurrent Kafka consumer with the following configurations

spring.kafka.listener.concurrency=6
spring.kafka.consumer.max-poll-records=1

Does every service eventually consume from every partition?
Meaning at a given point in time one service consumes maybe partition 1-6 out of 12 but an hour later they might consume 6-12 out of 12?
I understand that the partition / consumer assignment is not sticky. So I assume I can set the listener concurrency to a number less than the number of partitions and this just means maybe a slower consumption overall?

Overall you are going to have 12 Kafka consumers in the same group. The group manager is going to distribute all those 12 partitions between all your consumers. However there is no guarantee which partition is going to land where. See PartitionAssignor for more info: https://www.conduktor.io/blog/kafka-partition-assignment-strategy/

Thanks Artem! One follow-up question: I read the linked article and as far as I understand: if the number on listener concurrency is lower (in total) than the number of partitions, the consumer will do according to the PartitionAssignor a round-robin or similar to fetch from all partitions. So still all partitions will be consumed, correct?

That's correct. No one partition is left behind in case of consumer group management.
